# How to Auto-Populate Dates Between Two Given Dates in Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have been trying to achieve what has been explained on [this](https://infoinspired.com/google-docs/spreadsheet/auto-populate-dates-between-two-given-dates-in-google-sheets/) link.

I have two dates in a `Google Sheet`. One start date and another end date (in a cell). I want now to populate all the dates between these two dates in a row. The link above explains how to do it in a column but doesn't explain how to do in a `row`.

I have tried many things. I learnt about `R1C1` notation and my last attempt was with:

```
=ArrayFormula(edate(B2,COLUMN(R[0]C[0]:indirect("R[0]C[" & datedif(B2,B3,"M") & "]", false))))
```

But it returns parsing error. What is possibly wrong with my code?

Comment: Have you tried [TRANSPOSE function](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094262?hl=en) ?

Comment: Is there any method without TRANSPOSE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend to use [custom function](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions) alternative:

[image]

where DATES_BETWEEN is defined as follows:

```
function DATES_BETWEEN(dateFrom, dateTo) {
  Logger.log(dateFrom);
  Logger.log(dateTo);
  var t = dateFrom.getTime(),
      tMax = dateTo.getTime(),
      values = [];
  while (t <= tMax) {
    values.push(new Date(t));
    t += 24000 * 3600;
  }
  return [values];
}
```

The function should return 2d-array to fit as a single row cells.

Answer (score 0):

Does the folloing work for you?

Place "transpose" in the formula from the link you referred to:

Original formula at link: `=ArrayFormula(TO_DATE(row(indirect("A"&A2):indirect("A"&B2))))`

With TRANSPOSE: `=ArrayFormula(TRANSPOSE(TO_DATE(row(indirect("A"&A2):indirect("A"&B2))))`